# Printf function prints another string too

Tags: c, string, char, printf

Hi i am fairly new in C language and i was trying to understand the strings. As i know, strings are just an array of characters and there shouldn't be a difference between `char a[]= "car"` and `char a[] = {'c','a','r'}`.

When i try to print the string as:

```
char a[] = "car";
char b[] = "testing the cars";
printf("%s", a);
```

the output is just car and there's no problem.But when i try to print it as:

```
char a[] = {'c','a','r'};
char b[] = "testing the cars";
printf("%s", a);
```

it's printing the b too. Can you explain what's the reason of it?

Comment: Strings in C are arrays of characters **terminated by a null character**.  Your second `char a[]` isn't.

Comment: sorry, i forgot the apostrophe. i fixed the question.

Comment: It is possible for `printf` to also print the array `char a[] = {'c','a','r'};` If you want to print a `char` array that is not necessarily terminated by a null character, then you must tell `printf` the maximum length of the array to print, so that it does not try to access the array out of bounds while searching for the end of the string. In this case, you would have to change `printf("%s", a);` to `printf("%.3s", a);`. See the documentation for [printf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) for further information. However, it is generally better to always use a null terminator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%s` specifier of `printf()` expects a `char*` pointer to a **null-terminated** string.

In the first case, `a` and `b` are both null-terminated.  Initializing a `char[]` array of unspecified size with a string literal will *include* the literal's null-terminator `'\0'` character at the end.  Thus:

`char a[] = "car";`

is equivalent to:

`char a[] = {'c', 'a', 'r', '\0'};`

In the second case, `a` is NOT null-terminated, leading to *undefined behavior*, as `printf("%s", a)` will read past the end of `a` into surrounding memory until it eventually finds a `'\0'` character.  It just *happens* that, in your case, `b` exists in that memory following `a`, but that is not guaranteed, the compiler can put `b` wherever it wants.